# How to get profile ID using sandbox subscription button after subscription..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paypal-subscriptions

I am using subscription button for paypal subscription,it subscribe successfully and get response with these variables

{"**membership**":"premium","**tx**":"3AC523383D6811202","**st**":"Completed","**amt**":"39.95","**cc**":"USD","**cm**":"","**item_number**":"SID-TAG-PREM","**sig**":"oiYcbtrbpadEFfwJmm9Q45gL/y8jk6exfAmovrm2X07K31gzc3MFGCAoxlIlIssWvxuzGlp4ceDvSiS6qcuW6sQT4mcx+hczRIcnmEY/+q83Qk8jdoYYGG5AUo34kJwsTACf2K9KMWqPGe/0NS2Q2+e+pO1nc3M++IVHiRya33k=","**action**":"payment_success","**controller**":"paypal_transactions"}

My subscription button code:-

But I need profile_id also,and I have used IPN also but didn't get Profile ID. Please suggest me what to do??

Comment: https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring did you create recurring profile?...se answer is on this gem...thanks

Comment: Are'nt you getting recurring_payment_id in params?

Comment: Yes, I have created recurring profile @RajarshiDas

Comment: no, I am not getting recurring_payment_id @techvineet